# How to fix Intel 320 Series SSD bug?

Tags: ssd

Intel 320 series MLC SSD is known to have a 'Bad Context 13x Error' bug

http://communities.intel.com/thread/23610?tstart=0

Apparently the firmware to fix the bug will not be released before the end of August.

I have recently ordered 2 of the 320s to replace my current server's SATA disks. So I am wondering how risky is the bug and how to update the firmware? (I don't have physical access to the server)

Comment: Don't install the disks (to production) until you've applied the update.

Comment: I couldn't find an official release date on the Intel forum, for this problem.  Will probably buy one of these drives soon, but wait to install until the firmware is ready.

Comment: [Updated post "withing two weeks" of 8/13](http://communities.intel.com/thread/24121?tstart=0) for the firmware fix.

Answer (score 1):

The "8mb bug" seems to be a problem for a specific set of the 320's. I bought one for an older Unibody Macbook Pro and it has been nothing but awesome. One of the biggest issues that spark the problem is an unexpected loss of power. Keep the laptop/desktop powered up and everything should be ok.

Worst case scenario is that you sit on the drives until the firmware update has been released. I didn't and I don't recommend doing this but, it is an option. As a baseline mine is the 120gig model (supposedly heavily affected). If the drives are bound for Macs you could also implement a rigorous backup plan along with a bootable clone.

Comment: Does the bug affect only 120 gigs or all of the 320 production in a certain time frame?

Comment: @hnns Judging from comments on various websites, the "8mb bug" seems to affect other 320 models as well, 160GB version for instance.

Comment: @Chris O: Is there a way to determine whether my disks are among the bad breed?

Comment: @hnns I don't see anything posted by Intel regarding specific disks that have the bug.